# Infinitely many points in bounded $E$ means infinitely many limit points and a finite number of non-limit points

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have been thinking about limit points and I have thought of the following question:

> If a set is bounded, and has infinitely many points, are there necessarily a finite number of non-limit points.

If $E$ has infinitely many points in a bounded region, we have a finite number(or zero) non-limit points. My thought is, if we had an infinite number of non-limit points, wouldn't that mean we would have to pack them into increasing less space, and continuing to do this infinitely we are essentially converging on every point in $E$.

Comment: Bounded in where, the real numbers? A general metric space?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews A general metric space(but the picture I was working with was a closed ball)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $E=[0,1]$ inside $[0,2]$.  All the points in $(1,2]$ are non-limit points, an uncountable infinity. All of $E$ are limit points, so there are an uncountable number of them as well.  If you insist that the limit points not be part of $E$, let $E = [0,1] \cap \Bbb Q$ and you have an uncountable infinity of limit points that are not part of $E$.

Answer (score 0):

In $[0,1]$ the set $\{1,1/2,1/3,...\}$ has only $0$ as a limit point.

The set of **non limit points**, which is what you conjectured to be finite is $(0,1]$ is very large.

Comment: He asked that $E$ have an infinite number of limit points.

Comment: What about infinitely many points bounded in $\Bbb C$? Are there now necessarily a finite number(or zero) of non-limit points?

Comment: @Understand:  my example carries over to $\Bbb C$ with no change as $\Bbb {R \subset C}$

Comment: @RossMillikan Oh very true, haha. I guess working with a (necessarily) 2D image in my thoughts didn't help(rather than just working with the real line)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes apologies for the phrasing, I am not very comfortable with the language of this subject as of yet. Thanks very much for your time though, sorry that I caused this exchange(with my strange phrasing)

Comment: No reason to apologize, @Understand. It happens all the time, and you weren't being rude.